# What is the meaning of like better?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is an excerpt from the book "Steps to Understanding":

> Then Fred married.His wife,Betty was very nice,but **she liked better newspapers than Fred.**

Which meaning is correct?

> 1. Betty likes newspapers more than her husband (she prefers a newspaper to her husband). or
> 2. Betty likes a better newspaper then Fred's newspaper. or
> 3. Betty's interest in newspapers is more than Fred's interest in newspapers.

I can provide the complete text if needed.

----Edit: Complete text of the story and the image (page 48, lesson 23 of the book)

[image: steps to understanding lesson 23 - Fred and Betty]

Fred Williams worked in a factory with a lot of other men. They talked and laughed a lot, and at lunch time they sat together and read newspapers and laughed about the pictures in them.

Then Fred married. His wife, Betty, was very nice, **but she liked better newspapers than Fred.** Every day a boy brought Fred's newspaper and Betty's newspaper to the house, and Fred took his to the factory and left Betty's in the hall. Once or twice he looked at hers, but he did not like it, and sometimes in the evening he said to Betty, `Why do you read that paper? I hate it.`

But last Monday Fred said to his wife, `There was something very nice in that newspaper yesterday.`

Betty was happy. `Oh!` she said, `that's good, Fred. What was that?`

Fred laughed and said, `My friend Bill's lunch. He brought it to work in the newspaper.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed, it's #2. When I read it, I understand it to mean *Betty prefers to read* (i.e., likes) *higher-quality* (i.e., better) *newspapers than does Fred.*